# VSTO: Speeding up adding tasks in MS Project using VSTO

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I am using my VSTO to add roughly 3000 tasks to MS Project. The problem is that it adds very slowly - approximately 28-30 mins (and sometimes even more).

I am making sure to disable screen updates using: Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;

Is there a known workaround to this problem or is this just a limitation of VSTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Project 2010 works faster with COM than Project 2007
2. Disable automatic calculations: set Application.Calculation to PjCalculation.pjManual
3. Hide Gant Chart - keep just a grid on the screen
4. Call Marshal.ReleaseComObject for interface objects you no longer need

Comment: Thanks... Yes MS Project 2010 seems to work amazingly fast as compared to MS Project 2007. I have another performance concern, but I will create a new question out of it.

Comment: How do I programatically hide the Gantt chart?

Comment: I usually do that manually, but probably there is a way to do that using some predefined view - I will be glad to hear about solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the experience that I've had with Project 2007. Your experience may vary of course :)

1. I've found that disabling automatic calculations does not provide that many benefits and may hurt the accuracy of futher calculations.
2. If you are using UndoTransactions, don't. This will have a MASSIVE impact on performance both in time processing and memory usage.
3. Calling ScreenUpdating has performance benefits but you must call it everytime before you process a task.
4. Also, an additional tip that is very weird. Try grabbing the title bar of the MS Project window or the title bar of the dialog you are using to process the tasks as if you were going to move it then don't release it. The importing will be many times faster.